# Attribute routing - every method, class or as needed?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

Let's say you have an API controller. Some methods of this controller use the same routes:

```
[HttpPost] // /api/entities
public IHttpActionResult Add(Entity entity)
{
  ...
}

[HttpGet] // /api/entities
public IHttpActionResult FindAll()
{
  ...
}

[HttpGet] // /api/entities
public IHttpActionResult Find(String name)
{
  ...
}

[HttpGet] // /api/entities/id
public IHttpActionResult Find(Int32 id)
{
  ...
}

[HttpDelete] /api/entities/id
public IHttpActionResult Remove(Int32 id)
{
  ...
}
```

Do I apply RouteAttribute to all methods or only to two methods to cover for "api/entities" and "api/entities/id"? Or is it better to apply two RouteAttribute to the class itself?

Answer (score 0):

If you have default routes specified in the configuration, that is:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "API Default",
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

You don't have to apply routing attributes, don't forget that requests will be mapped to the actions not only by HTTP method, but by parameter type also, so there should be no problem.

Take a look at the "Action" section of the [documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection)